# C++/CLI Form Application - Can't select from the database

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, mysql-connector

```
#pragma once 
using namespace System;
using namespace MySql::Data::MySqlClient; 

ref class Connect {

public:

    static String^ query=L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=test123"; 
    static MySqlConnection^ conDB = gcnew MySqlConnection(query); 
    static MySqlCommand^ cmdDatabase = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 199246-4444.table;", conDB); 
    static MySqlDataReader^ myReader; 

};
```

Hi the problem is that 'gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 199246-4444.table;", conDatabase);' isn't working. I can't select from my database and I believe it is because there is a dash between 199246 and 4444 which is causing the error. How do I fix this? I've tried to look for the same or atleast a similar problem on Stackoverflow but I can't find any, nor on Google. I don't want to change the database name.

The error I get is:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '199246-4444.table' at line 1"

When I try to use a database with text it totally works. However the DB name '199246-4444' isn't working.

Update:

I know I wrote that I couldn't connect to my Database. I ment to write that I couldn't select from the database instead. This fixed it:

```
static MySqlCommand^ cmdDatabase = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `199246-4444`.`table`;", conDB);
```

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the schema with `\``, such as `\`199246-4444\`.table `?

Comment: Just to note: Your code is C++/CLI -- It is not really C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
static MySqlCommand^ cmdDatabase = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `199246-4444`.`table`;", conDB);
```

ie, put the database name `199246-4444` in backticks ``.

Answer (score 1):

Before the `dash`, you have the database name. 
Specify the database in the [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/), and remove it from query.

```
static String^ query=L"datasource=localhost;Database=199246-4444;port=3306;username=root;password=test123";
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use this query from now on. Can't believe I didin't specify the database.